# General error 1215 while trying to make a foreign key within the same table, integer to integer

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to make a foreign key in the same table and no matter what I test I get an error.

In Connection.php line 647:

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `trip_tags` add constraint `trip_tags_parent_foreign` foreign key (`parent`) refer
  ences `trip_tags` (`id`) on delete cascade)

In Connection.php line 449:

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint

This is my code

```
    Schema::create('trip_tags', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = "InnoDB";
        $table->uuid('uuid')->unique();
        $table->integer('id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('name')->nullable();
        $table->integer('parent')->unsigned()->nullable();

        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::table('trip_tags', function (Blueprint $table) {

        $table->foreign('parent')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('trip_tags')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

I try to point parent to id, both are unsigned integers, I guess the reason that creating the foreign key fails is that they are not compatible in some way, I cant figure out what is wrong.

I tried to point parent to uuid but then had to make it a string and that worked. But I have to have the parent point to id which is integer and I cant get it to migrate withour error.

Comment: [`uuid`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) !== `unsigned integer`

Comment: hi devk? I am not pointing to the uuid column, just to the id named column, got any ideas what could be going on?

Comment: Oh, sorry. My mistake. Then I believe the error happens because you don't have an index on `id`. Try adding `unique()` to it.

Comment: that was it! do you want to post a real answer I can upvote and select as correct?

Comment: Happy to help :) Posted it as an answer as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your `id` column doesn't have an index on it.

Add `->unique()` to the declaration:

```
$table->integer('id')->unsigned()->unique();
```